# Select from 3 tables with IN clause

Tags: sql, in-clause

Need to display next: all fNAME and lNAME from table username that have position of "Admin" and work in 'ABC' company (NAME_COMPANY), with IN clause.

```
create table company 
(
    CODE_COMPANY char(30),
    NAME_COMPANY varchar2(30) not null,
    MAIL_COMPANY varchar2(30) null,

    constraint PK_CODE_COMPANY primary key (CODE_COMPANY),
);

create table USERNAME 
(
    NAME_USERNAME varchar2(30),
    USER_LOCATION number,
    fNAME varchar2 (30) not null,
    lNAME varchar2 (30) not null,
    PHONE_USER char(13) null,
    USER_POSITION varchar2 (30),
    check (USER_POSITION in('Admin', 'Superadmin', 'Technician', 'Student')),

    constraint PK_NAME_USERNAME primary key (NAME_USERNAME),
    constraint FK_USER_LOCATION foreign key (USER_LOCATION) references uLOCATION (LOCATION)
);

create table uLOCATION 
(
    LOCATION number,
    CODE_COMPANY char(30),
    NAME_LOCATION varchar2(30) not null,
    FLOOR_LOCATION varchar2(10),
    check (FLOOR_LOCATION in ('MAIN_FLOOR', '1ST FLOOR', '2ND FLOOR', '3RD FLOOR')),

    constraint PK_LOCATION primary key (LOCATION),
    constraint FK_CODE_COMPANY_L foreign key (CODE_COMPANY) references company (CODE_COMPANY),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
select u.*
from username u
where u.user_position = 'admin' and
      u.ulocation in (select l.location
                      from ulocation l join
                           ucompany c
                           on l.code_company = c.code_company
                      where c.name_company = 'ABC'
                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the following query. Not sure why you would use an IN instead of a standard = however I've included both with one commented.

```
select
    user.fName,
    user.lName
from
    username as user
    inner join ulocation as location
        on location.location = user.user_location
    inner join company as company
        on company.code_company = location.code_company
where
    user.user_position = 'Admin'
    and name_company in ('A','B','C') -- not needed if only checking for one company
                                      -- if only one company, change to: name_company = 'ABC'
```

Comment: The IN needs to be used instead of inner join. is possible that?